# Which will be the better way or more performance oriented while dealing with Maps in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a Method say func_1 and i am returning a Map from it.

Then i want to iterate this Map and want to operate on the contents of it(record-by-record) in my second method say func_2.

What will be the better way to do it. Like should i pass the entire Map[String,String] as an Argument to my 2nd method 'func_2' and then Iterate and process it within 'func_2' OR..OR.. i should make 'Func_2' to accept a (String,String) Tuple as an Argument and then use the resultmap.map(x => func_2(x_1, x_2)). Another angle to this is .. Should i use `VAL` instead of `def` for creating functions as the `val` will be called just once.
Below is the code :

**Function:1**

```
val func_1 = (path:String)  => {
    val inputBufferedSource = Source.fromFile(path)
    val indexMap = inputBufferedSource.getLines().map(x => (x.split(",")(0).toLowerCase.trim, x.split(",")(1).toLowerCase.trim)).toMap
    inputBufferedSource.close()
    indexMap
  }:Map[String,String]

val func_2 = <Signature & logic>
```

Now which would be better 
`val func_2(x:String, y:String)` 
**OR** 
`val func_2(inMap:Map[String,String])`

And then .. Calling it

```
val resultMap = obj.func_1(args(0))
resultMap.map(x => obj.func_2(x._1,x._2)) // This will call the method for every iteration But if it is val then only once i guess
```

**OR**

```
val resultMap = obj.func_1(args(0))
obj.func_2(resultMap) // Here method is called just once
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with whichever is simpler and clearer, and this is heavily dependent on context and implementation. I am almost certain there will not be a performance difference. Reading the file from disk will surely dominate whatever extra time you save by avoiding an extra stack frame or whatever. The best way to do performance optimization is to actually measure and test it, anyway.

Generally you should write functions using `def`. It's more typical style, and avoids instantiating an extra function object. Of course there are exceptions, but I don't see any reason to do so in this case.

Comment: Where is the Extra Function Object ??? Also just leave the Disk Reading part that is anyway required. I am more focused on the approach whether to iterate a map and pass a Tuple which will call the method multiple times OR just pass the Map as an argument which will call the method only once and further processing will be done in the respective called function

Comment: `val func_1 = (path:String)  => ...` allocates a `Function1` object and assigns it to `func_1`. `def func_1(path: String) ...` does not. And I understand from your question what you are focused on and my answer is to not focus on that and go with whichever you think is simpler. Or else implement both and see if you can measure a difference (my guess is you won't be able to).

Comment: Then what is the use of creating functions using a val ?? Isn't it the good practice ..?

Comment: If, for instance, you have a frequent need to return the function itself as an object, or pass it in directly to another function/method call. If all you are doing is calling the function, then you should probably use `def`. There's a lot of good info out there if you search "scala method vs function".